# Django Forms: How to avoid hidden input, without changing URL

Tags: python, django

I have run into a problem that I cannot completely wrap my head around.

I have a model `Question` that among other things contains a statement, information about the user that asked it, as well as information on amount of yes-votes and no-votes.

In a template, I have a situation similar to the following one:

```
{% for question in list_passed_with_questions %}
 <p>{% question.statement %}</p>

 <form method="post">
  {% csrf_token %}

  {{ vote_form.as_p }} #vote_form makes the user choose between 'yes'/'no'

  <button type="primary">Think</button>

 </form>

{% endfor %}
```

My objective is to be able to know which `question` each user votes for. Suppose I have a `list of questions` in my `template`, each one with a `form` that allows a user to vote - then how could I know which one the user voted for when using their input in `views.py`? Regardless of whether the `vote_form` is a `Form` or `ModelForm` instance, `request.POST` will only contain information about the user's yes/no-choice (that is, it will not contain for example the `pk` of question).

One way to solve this would be to have the `submit button` lead to a new `url`, and pass the `pk` of the question answered as a `slug`.

Another way I though of would be to specify a `hidden-input` field that passes the `question-object's pk.`

**Now** - is there another method I could use to differentiate between the various `questions`, besides changing the `url` and allowing for `hidden input`?

**Furthermore** - if I make sure to validate the `hidden input`, and check that the `pk` passed through that `hidden-input field` belongs to a `question` that the user is allowed to vote for, would that be a responsible and safe way to do it?

Answer (score 0):

Another way would be using AJAX

```
<button type="button" onclick="Voting(vote, pk)">Think</button>
```

In addition, AJAX allows you to communicate with the server without doing a page refresh